# Swift3 UITextField change placeholder font type and size

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

Code:

```
txtField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:strPlaceHolder, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(color:PlaceHolderColor, alpha:1.0),NSFontAttributeName :UIFont(name: "Didot-Italic", size: 4)!])
```

I am trying to change the `UITextField` placeholder font type and font size. It is not working. What is wrong with my code? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: This line: txtField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Hello World", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green, NSFontAttributeName :UIFont(name: "Didot-Italic", size: 4)!]) is working for me, inside of viewWillAppear.

Comment: sorry for delay reply.txtField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Hello World", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green, NSFontAttributeName :UIFont(name: "Didot-Italic", size: 4)!]).
txtField.Font = UIFont (name: "Didot", size:12.0).i try to use different font style for place holder and text.can i do so

Answer (score 6):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    txtField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Place holder text in here", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 153.0/255.5, green: 153.0/255.5, blue: 153.0/255.5, alpha: 0.5)])
}
```

place holder attribute text will be same as your textfield text attribute in size and font

Answer (score 0):

you should change a font attribute of the text field (i.e. txtField.font) and then set your place holder text (i.e. txtField.placeholder)

Comment: This comment actually makes sense and should not be downvoted. For some reason, if you first set attributedPlaceholder with 1 font and then configure font of the field itself, it will override the font that you have set in attributedPlaceholder.
So always configure textField properties (like font) before setting something custom in attributedPlaceholder.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5 / XCode 11:**

UITextField has a property called .attributedPlaceholder you can assign attributes using NSAttributedString Keys.  To customize a "searchBoxTextField" placeholder to:
light gray text color &
Times New Roman font of size 20

try copying/pasting this & it should work...

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBoxTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Enter a Word" attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font :UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 20)!])

    }
```

note: You can still use Auto Layout selections to control the text appearance entered by the user.  So in this example, the placeholder is gray, but if you selected black for the textView text color it will transition nicely when the user types into the box.

[image: placeholder gray, small, Times New Roman]

[image: user-entered text white, bold, Futura]